# Change master table PK and update related table FK (changing PK from Autoincrement to UUID on Mysql)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, uuid, create-table

I have two related tables: Groups and Clients. Clients belongs to Groups so I have a foreign key "group_id" that references the group a client belongs to.

I'm changing the Group id from an autoincrement to a UUID. So what I need is to generate a UUID for each Group and update the Clients table at once to reflect the changes and keep the records related.

Is there a way to do this with multiple-table update on MySQL?

Adding tables definitions for clarification.

```
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$


CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1'
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fkgp` (`group_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fkgp` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `groups` (`id`) 
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

Comment: Your user table has any foreign key constraint ? Can you post your table definition (show create table name;).

Comment: @golja, I added the tables definition statements as requested.

Comment: Hmmm if i am not wrong isn't the main idea about ON UPDATE CASCADE to allow you to change the primary key value and any tables that have foreign key references to the value will be changed automatically ? So basically you don't need to do anything :)

Comment: @golja You're right, I always put that rules when apply, and now I just forgot why I put them there. Thanks.